# A DNS record that will frequently change?

Tags: domain-name-system

How do I make a domain record that can change frequently?

Let's say `example.org` points to `203.0.113.0`. Two minutes later it has to point to `198.51.100.0`.

It will be normal web sites behind the domain ("normal" only in the the sense of being accessed using common web browsers) but with very short lifespan. Domain will point to an address for 3-4 hours at most before it gets switched or shut down. There is no need to protect the DNS server from frequent queries.

My approach would be to set TTL to 60 seconds and simply change the record when switch has to be made. In worst case scenario it would cause a user to wait for max 60 seconds before a new server is accessible.

Somehow I don't trust in this... Some ISPs or browsers could ignore or override the TTL, couldn't they? If it's a valid concern what would be a reasonable TTL to be expected?

Thank you!

Comment: Why exactly do you need this capability?  What kind of "normal web site" runs on infrastructure that disappears after 3-4 hours?  There are solutions that come to mind, but it's not clear what you're doing with fast DNS changes or what behavior you expect during transitions.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, "normal" in the sense it is a web application accessed via browser but it's far from being a classic web site. A single application instance will indeed have lifespan of few hours. I just want to use shared pool of domain names for them. I already got advise to look into load balancing technique. But because application instances are not interchangeable I am not sure its applicable at all.

Comment: In my experience, the vagueries of the Internet make DNS a poor candidate for 'service following'. Whilst it may work on your machine, or even your company network, or on your friend's flaky broadband, it seems that across the world there are some truly terrible clients that take many multiples of your TTL to notice any change in your DNS.

Comment: Why not an ip failover instead?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is called [Fast Flux DNS Records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_flux). And it's usually how malware authors hide their infrastructure servers.

While this will work for your plan, it's not the best plan. You will likely need to have a spare server or more, online, and doing nothing almost all the time. Only when you have an issue with the main server you would switch to the next one.

Even if you have a TTL of 1 minute, one record will most likely be valid for more than that:

1. Browser caches

   Browsers usually cache the DNS records for a variable amount of time. Firefox uses [60 seconds](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.dnsCacheExpiration), Chrome uses [60 seconds](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=65570) too, IE 3.x and earlier cached for [24 hours](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/263558/how-internet-explorer-uses-the-cache-for-dns-host-entries), IE 4.x and above cached for 30 minutes.
2. OS cache

   Windows will [not usually honour the TTL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn305896(v=ws.11).aspx). A TTL for DND is not like the TTL for a IPv4 packet. It's more a indication of freshness than a mandatory refresh. Linux can have nscd configured to set the amount of time the user wants, disregarding DNS TTL. It can cache entries for a week, for example.
3. ISP cache

   ISPs can (and some will) use aggressive caching for decreasing the traffic. They can not only change TTL, but cache the records and return it to clients without even asking upstream DNS servers. This is more prevalent on mobile ISPs, as they change the TTL so mobile clients don't complain on traffic latency.

A load balancer is made to do exactly what you want. With a load balancer in place, you can have 2 or 4 or 10 servers all online at the same time, dividing the load. If one of them goes offline, the service will not be affected. Changing DNS records will have a downtime between the time when the server goes off and the DNS is changed. It will take more than one minute, because you have to detect the downtime, change the records, and wait for them to propagate.

So use a load balancer. It's made to do what you want, and you know exact what to expect. A fast flux DNS setup will have mixed and inconsistent results.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer! `example.org` and word `switch` might have been misleading. In my scenario I need this for multiple separate and independent instances of an application that are started at request and reuse domains from a shared pool of domain names (`server1.example.org`, `server2.example.org` etc).

Comment: Even so, use a load balancer. You will have high availability, a flexible pool, logs, lots of metrics and statistics, can priorise one server or another, and less headache.

Comment: Yes, you're likely to find that some awful ISP somewhere takes hours or a whole day to pick up your DNS change.

Comment: Besides bot nets, this is also the way Dynamic DNS works if you are behind a dialup line whose IP address changes on every connection.

Comment: @glglgl: Does dial-up even exist anymore?

Comment: @Mehrdad Depending on how you define it, it does. In Germany, if you have an ADSL line, you have to authenticate via PPPoE and then you get assigned an IP address from the dial-up range. Until recently (and on some lines, still), your connection was cut-off after 24 h, so you had to re-login (or your CPE did it for you).

Comment: To add to @glglgl's comment: The crucial point is that you were assigned another IP address *every* time you re-logged in. This behavior was by intention: The providers wanted to prevent users from running servers in their SOHOs that way.

Comment: @Binarus not only this, but usually an ISP with 2000 subscribers don't have 2000 IPs on their pool. As not every one customer will be active at the same time, as soon as some user disconnects, another can connect and grab the same IP.

Comment: @ThoriumBR that might have been a consideration in the early days when people would have a single PC hooked up to the ADSL modem, which would be in use for significantly less than 24 hrs/day. These days, most people are behind ADSL routers which reconnect as soon as they are disconnected (not that many people bother turning them off when not in use), thus subscribers claim an IP from the pool most of the time.

Comment: "_A TTL for DND is not like the TTL for a TCP packet._" TCP segments do not have a TTL. There is a TTL in the IPv4 header so that an IPv4 packet has a maximum lifetime of 4.25 minutes. IPv6 has done away with TTL in favor of Hop Limit to restrict based on the number of hops rather than a maximum time period.

Comment: @RonMaupin my bad, corrected!

Answer (score 7):

DNS and how it works is perhaps accompanied by more  misunderstanding, legend, superstition, and mythology as any aspect of IT.

Even those of us who know that we are essentially lying (or at least drastically oversimplifying) when we talk about "propagation" of changes still tend to use the term to describe something that is -- simultaneously -- extremely simple and straightforward... yet difficult to explain... and has nothing to do with propagation *per se*, but everything to do with caching and negative caching, both of which are an essential component of how the system works (and, arguably, how it avoids outright collapse under its own weight) -- essentially the inside-out, opposite of actual "propagation," pull -- not push.

For all the worrying and hand-wringing about short TTLs, they tend to work more often than not, to the point that it may be in your interests to simply try them.  At ${day_job}, when our sites migrate from an "old" platform to a "new" platform, it often means they are migrating in such a way that nothing in the infrastructure is shared.  My first step in such a migration is dropping the TTL to 60s far enough in advance of the cut so that the old TTL has multiple multiples of itself to run out, giving me a reasonable assurance that these transitional RRs with short TTLs will "propagate out."  When I am ready for the cut, I reconfigure the old balancer¹ to hairpin traffic to the new system -- across the Internet -- such that the balancer is no longer balancing multiple internal systems, but instead, is "balancing" all the requests to a single external system -- the balancer of the new platform.²

Then I cutover the DNS, and watch the new balancer and the old.

I am always pleasantly surprised at how rapidly the transition occurs.  The holdouts seem to almost always be search spiders and third party "health checking" sites that inexplicably latch on to the old records.

But there's one scenario that breaks down predictably: when a user's browser windows remain open, they tend to latch to the already-discovered address, and often it persists until all of their browser windows are closed.

But in the above narrative, you find the solution to the problem: a "load balancer" -- specifically and more precisely, a reverse proxy -- can be the system that your exposed DNS record points to.

The reverse proxy then forwards the request to the correct target IP address, which it resolves using a second "dummy" hostname with a short TTL, which points to the real back-end server.³ Because the proxy always honors the DNS TTL on that dummy DNS entry, you are assured of a rapid and complete switchover.

The down-side is that you may be routing the traffic through unnecessary extra infrastructure, or paying more for transport across multiple network boundaries, redundantly.

There are services that provide this kind of capability on a global scale, and the one with which I am most familiar is CloudFront.  (Most likely, Cloudflare would serve exactly the same purpose, as the small amoubt of testing I have done indicates that it also behaves correctly, and I'm sure there are others.)

Although primarily marketed as a CDN, CloudFront is at its core a global network of reverse proxies with the capability of *optionally* caching the responses.  If `www.example.com` points to CloudFront and CloudFront is configured to forward these requests to `backend.example.com`, and the DNS record for `backend.example.com` uses a short TTL, then CloudFront will do the right thing, because it does honor that short TTL.  When the back-end record changes, the traffic will all migrate by the time the TTL runs down.

The TTL on the front-side record pointing to CloudFront, and whether browsers and caching resolvers are honoring it is unimportant, because changes to the back-end destination do not require changes on the `www.example.com` record... so the notion that "The Internet" has, with regard to the correct target for `www.example.com` is consistent, regardless of where the back-end system happens to be.

This, to me, solves the problem completely by relieving the browser of any need to "follow" changes to the origin server's IP.

tl; dr: route the requests to a system that serves as a proxy for the real web server, so that only the proxy configuration needs to accommodate the change in origin server IP -- not the browser-facing DNS.

Note that CloudFront also minimizes latency by some DNS magic it imposes on the front side, which results in `www.example.com` resolving to the most optimal CloudFront edge location based on the location of the browser that's querying `www.example.com`, so there is minimal chance of traffic taking an unnecessarily circuitous route from browser to edge to origin... but this part is transparent and automatic and outside the scope of the question.

And, of course, content caching may also be of value by reducing load on the origin server or transport -- I have configured web sites on CloudFront where the origin server was on an ADSL circuit, and ADSL is inherently constrained for upstream bandwidth.  The origin server where CloudFront connects in order to fetch the content does not need to be a server inside the AWS ecosystem.

---

¹ I speak of balancer as a single entity when in fact it has multiple nodes.  When the balancer is an ELB, a machine behind the balancer acts as a dummy app server and does the actual hairpinning to the new platform's balancer, since ELB can't do this on its own.

² The new balancer's only knowledge about the old one is that it needs to trust the old balancer's X-Forwarded-For and that it should not do any IP-based rate limiting on the old balancer's source addresses.

³ When the proxy is one or more servers you control, you have the option of skipping using DNS on the back-side, and simply using IP addresses in the proxy config, but the hosted/distributed scenario discussed subsequently needs that second layer of DNS.

Comment: Thanks, as always, for another great answer. "At ${day_job}, when our sites migrate from an "old" platform to a "new" platform, [...]": Been there, done that. +1!

Answer (score 4):

When I change DNS records, often times the old IP address will be used for months. Having said that, a TTL of only a few seconds is what Amazon uses to create fallback service, for example.

Instead of changing DNS, you can put a proxy server / load balancer in front of it.

Comment: In my tests `TTL` 60 seconds seems to working most of the time, but I had some clients which experienced a delay around 10-20 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using Dynamic DNS.  This is designed for precisely the scenario that @glglgl mentioned in a comment above.  I believe they use a low TTL which, as was pointed out earlier, may not be 100% effective since clients are free to ignore it. But it works "pretty well".

Even if you aren't changing your IP frequently, it's important to keep your TTL reasonable.  Many years ago, the company I used to work for changed ISPs which caused our IPs to change.  Unfortunately, we had set our TTL to something ridiculous like a month so the old DNS records were being held onto for a long time.

Comment: There are a lot of ISP level DNS servers out there not honoring TTL.  I work on a product that switches DNS information about twice a year.  We have a lot of folks who's DNS servers cache our old information for up to several weeks after we change it.  Unless you control the client side don't count on this working well.